# How to enable volume slider of Player tone.js inside of useEffect hook(react)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, volume, use-effect, tone.js

I'm currently trying to adjust the volume of a Player component provided by tone.js.

I initiated a new Player and utilized useRef to save a reference of the object in `current`.

the Player contains keys like url, loop, volume etc.

Outside of the useEffect I have a few eventhandlers which control the play and stop methods as well as a loop button that toggles the state of loop inside useEffect. They all work.

The problem I am facing is that whenever I want to adjust the volume, useEffect is being called, which leads to a rerender.

**I basically want to be able to change the key parameter(value) for volume inside the created Player object. When moving the slider react rerenders but the volume doesn't change.**

I just put this out her hoping someone has done this before.

My previous question has been left unanswered and eventually I solved it myself.
It seems there are just not many people working with the web audio API I assume.

I believe though in this case I just need someone skilled in react.

There's probably an easy workaround but I just lack the knowledge.

I started learning react a couple of weeks ago.

Here is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import "./DrumMachine.css";
import Button from "./Button";
import { Player } from "tone";
import Sound from "./sound.wav";
import Poti from './Poti';

export default function DrumMachine() {
  console.log("body")
  const [value, setValue ] = useState(0);
  const [loop, setLoop] = useState(false);

  const playerRef = useRef(null);
  playerRef.current = new Player(Sound).toDestination();


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect")
    console.log(playerRef.current.volume)
    playerRef.current.loop = loop;
    playerRef.current.volume = value;
  },[loop, value]);
 
  const play = () => {
    playerRef.current.start();
  };

  const stop = () => {
    playerRef.current.stop();
  }

  const volume = (event) => {
    console.log(value)
    setValue(event.target.value)
  }

  const loopToggle = () => {
    console.log('loop')
    setLoop(!loop);
  }
  const doSt = () => {
    console.log('loop')
  }


  return (
    <div className="machine">
      <Button onClick={play}>Play</Button>
      <Button onClick={stop}>Stop</Button>
      <Button onClick={loopToggle}>
        {loop ? 'Loop active' : 'Loop disabled'}
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={doSt}>
        {'Do something'}
      </Button>
      <Button></Button>
      <Button></Button>
      <Button></Button>
      <Button></Button>
      <span className='vol-box'>
        <label htmlFor='vol' >Volume</label>
        <Poti 
        onChange={volume} 
        value={value} id='volM' 
        name='vol' 
        min='0' 
        max='1'
        step='0.1'
        ></Poti>
      </span>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

The console.logs are obviously just for testing. I will read the docs meanwhile hoping to find solution.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're creating your Player inside the useEffect?
And what could lead to render loops here?

Comment: I followed this setup from tone.js: https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/wiki/Using-Tone.js-with-React-or-Vue. And came across this post while looking for anwers : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170825/infinite-re-renders-when-updating-usestate-from-streaming-audio-function

Comment: As far as I understand mutating state of useRef doesn't cause a rerender. If I change the state of loop and initiated the player outside of effect it would rerender the player each time anything changes. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You're right about useRef, but your use of useEffect is a bit counter-productive here I think. Your useEffect executes whenever loop or value change, which doesn't seem to be what you want. Have you tried just keeping your new Player inside useState, and having useEffect simply update its properties?

Comment: You could also do a simple conditional in the useEffect to check wether your Player is already initialized (defined), and if so, only update the properties.

Comment: I have updated the code. I initiated Player outside the scope of useEffect this time but whenever I change the volume via user input react still rerenders...well because it' still being changed inside useEffects. Not sure if you meant to just define the Player outside of useEffect as I still need to use reference for it to work. Kinda feel the anwser is pretty easy I'm just a bit too dumb to get it at the moment. Hope you might be able to point me at the exact error here. Thanks

Comment: `useEffect` triggers a rerender every time one of its dependencies (in the array) change. That's the whole point of `useEffect`. Does this cause the sound to stop playing? What's the reason you need to prevent the rerender?

Comment: Can you move the player to a higher level component, pass the player as a prop, and just have the controls rerender?

Comment: Sorry, sometimes you don't see the wood for all the trees...It takes me a while to understand the whole concept of react...either way...I was actually just trying to adjust the volume which doesn't work. The player doesn't stop anymore but creates some weird side effects like disabling the stop button function.

Comment: Did you try getting rid of the `useEffect` and just put the `playerRef.current.volume = value;` in your `volume` on change handler?

Comment: Just one note: you are logging the wrong value on volume change: `console.log(value)` should be `console.log(event.target.value)`. Are you sure the volume isn't changing?

Comment: I did.Didn't work. here's the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/web-audio-api-playground-v2-87dpx?file=/src/components/DrumMachine.js

Comment: I'm taking a look. I already discovered your volume min and max values are too small. I changed it to -20 and 20 and I can start a sound with the right volume. I'm just looking at how to change it on the fly.

Comment: `setLoop(loop => !loop);` your toggle will cause issues I think (maybe not the point here but good to know) You will get wrong states otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fork.

https://codesandbox.io/s/web-audio-api-playground-v2-forked-y1dc6?file=/src/components/DrumMachine.js

Okay, so a couple of things.

1. The volume min and max were too small to have a big impact. I set it -20 and 20 as the decibels and that was enough to notice a difference.
2. I declared your player outside of the component and passed it into the component as the ref initial value. This isn't the only way to do this, but it was the easiest to get your example working. This makes the player a singleton.

If you need to have multiple `DrumMachine` components. I recommend creating a player in its own component and passing functions to update it down to a controls component. This will allow your controls component to get rerendered on different button presses, but your player will not and you can have as many of them as needed.

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion in regards to the dB scale....but it only worked when I stop the loop and even then, just when I click on a new position of the slider instead of actually "sliding it. The whole purpose of this sandbox was just to find out how to configure the player. My actual project has a different set up in vs code. I would probably use an external volume component anyway. Nevertheless this was extremely helpful and I will follow your advice. Thanks